# How to remove symbols and add file name to fasta headers

Tags: bash, sed, header, cat, fasta

I have several fasta files with the following headers:

```
M01498:408:000000000-BLBYD:1:1101:11790:1823 1:N:0:1
```

I want to remove all symbols (colon, dash, and space), and add "barcodelabel=FILENAME;"

I can do it for one file using:

```
cat A1.fasta |sed s/-//g | sed s/://g| sed s/\ //g|sed 's/^>/>barcodelabel=A1;/g' >A1.renamed.fasta
```

How can I do this but for all of my files at once? I tried the code below but it didn't work:

```
for i in {A..H}{1..6}; do cat ${i}.fasta |sed s/-//g | sed s/://g| sed s/\ //g | sed 's/^>/>barcodelabel=${i};/g' >${i}.named.fasta; done
```

any help would be appreciated !

Comment: if you meant A1, A2, ..., H6, then try `for i in [A-H][1-6]; ...`. And better to use single sed  `sed 's/[-: ]//g'`

Answer (score 1):

Considering that you want to substitute `-`,`:` or space with null and want to add string at last of the first line then following may help you on same:

```
awk 'FNR==1{gsub(/:|-| +/,"");print $0,"barcodelabel=FILENAME";next} 1'  Input_file
```

In case you want to save output in to same Input_file then add following in above code too `> temp_file && mv temp_file  Input_file`

Comment: Hi thanks for the suggestions. I am not having trouble removing the symbols and adding "barcodelabel=FILENAME;" to my headers. My question was about how could  I get that command I posted to work for all my files at once. so I would not have to do it one by one (my files go from A1 to H6)

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out. First, I reduced the number of sed to simplify the code. The mistake was in the final sed I had simple quotation marks and it should have been double so it can read the ${i}. final code is:

```
for i in {A..H}{1..6}; do cat ${i}.fasta | 
sed 's/[-: ]//g' | 
sed "s/^>/>barcodelabel=${i};/g" > ${i}.final4.fasta; done
```

Comment: If you could tell us sample Input and expected output in more detailed manner then we could help you to shorten this too.

Comment: Hi, I have several samples that go from A1 to H6 (e.g. A1.fasta, H2.fasta, etc.). from each file, each sequence looks like this: 

M01498:408:000000000-BLBYD:1:1101:11790:1823 1:N:0:1

at the end I got each file having this as sequence header (this is the example for file A1.fasta)

>barcodelabel=A1;M01498408:000000000BLBYD111011179018231N01